# How can I controll the speed of a coreless motor with an RC receiver?

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, bjt, h-bridge, remote-control

We used a brushed ESC 1A 5V (0.4g) DSM-ESC001 (unable to find its manual) for controlling a coreless 614 motor with 8mA no-load rating with an FS-X6B receiver. After checking some things out, the ESC turned out to be 2-way, where the motor is rotating with half of its speed when the throttle stick on the RC transmitter is on its maximum position.

Is there a way to either recalibrate the transmitter or can we use another component which is light-weight, and dimensionally small, while still giving us the control over the speed of the coreless motor using the PWM signal from the RC Receiver?  We are currently using a  3.7V, 100mAh li-ion battery.